# Concat Two Bind Fields in DropDownList SelectedValue

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

I am trying to Concat to fields in the SelectedValye property of the Dropdownlist. I want to use Bind and not Eval. This is what I am using but it's not working. Is this possible to do?

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="RsmList" runat="server" DataSource="<%# ddRSM.DataSource %>" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("RSMLast") + '', '' + Bind("RSMFirst") %>'>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET 4.0? Or something lower?

Comment: why cant you try concatenating in sql query itself ???

Comment: @errorstacks that's probably not the best solution.  You shouldn't have to use SQL for presentation (concatenating fields, adding commas, etc) - that's what the .ASPX is for =)

Comment: @jadarnel27 no, thats actually the job of whatever is presenting that data to the view. Hence the Model/View/Presenter pattern, MVVM, or MVC. 'Some' pattern should be used here. This doesnt mean though it has to be in the sql query, this could be a custom object bound. IE query sql, copy into a new object. Unfortunately the built in ASP objects at times help prevent solid patterns.

Comment: @AdamTuliper That's actually what I was trying to convey - however, you have expressed it much more clearly.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont believe you can without using Eval because Bind translates actually to two separate method calls. You need to either use Eval() or do it before you databind. But - happy to be proven wrong : )

Comment: To Clarify - what I mean 'do it before you databind' is whatever object you bind to this modify it there. This is one reason a SQL Data (if thats what your source is) source isn't my choice here and I would rather bind in the code behind to my custom object with these fields in it. If you stick with a sql data source, then you need to change your query.

Comment: We definitely agree here -- I hate seeing data sources in markup (among other things).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need your `DataSource` inside binding tags -- I don't set this stuff up in markup, but I believe your reference should just be `DataSource="ddRSM.DataSource"`.

You should also be able to set your `SelectedValue` property like so:

```
SelectedValue='<%# Bind("RSMLast") %>, <%# Bind("RSMFirst") %>'
```

Comment: interesting.. never saw the syntax done like that with two separate calls together. Im curious if this works?

Comment: I should say that when I've done this, it was using `DataBinder.GetPropertyValue(Container.DataItem, "fieldName")`, and not using `Bind`, so it may not work perfectly. Alternatively, @errorstack's suggestion in the original comments makes a lot of sense to me, if @Justin has the access necessary to change the SQL query.

Comment: Bind translates into two separate calls behind the scenes thats why its hard for me to see this working conceptually.

Comment: @AdamTuliper, where have you read that online? I can't find anything in the MSDN documentation about it.

Comment: this touches upon it http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/archive/2007/06/29/how-asp-net-databinding-deals-with-eval-and-bind-statements.aspx